# Measuring 'consistency' of a slope

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

If you have a series of points (x,y). Is there a mathematical measurement that represents how consistent the slope of the line is.

Like, a straight line with a constant slope would be the highest rating possible using this measurement.

But, a line like the picture attached would be worse, because it flattens out during part of the plot.[image]

Comment: Weierstrass function is differentiable nowhere, so for a function that pathological, it doesn't make sense to talk about consistency of slope; the slope isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @user153582 You can still talk about how well a line approximates the function.

Answer (score 1):

In statistics, one often uses the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) $r$.
$r = 1$ for a linear function with positive slope, and $r = -1$ for a linear function with negative slope. This has the disadvantage of not being defined when the slope is $0$, but if not then $r^2$ is a good measure of "how consistent" the slope is.

Another possibility is, given points $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$, to simply take the standard deviation of the $n$ slopes.
That is, let
$$
m_i = \frac{y_{i+1} - y_i}{x_{i+1} - x_i}
$$
and find the standard deviation of $m_0, m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_{n-1}$.

Finally, maybe you want to consider longer intervals to be more significant than shorter intervals.
In this case, you could find the [weighted standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-standard-deviation-in-excel) of $m_0, m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_{n-1}$ with weights $w_i = (x_{i+1} - x_i)$.